# Can we enable cssAddon in Quasar with Vite plugin installation?

Tags: vite, quasar-framework

I have a Laravel 9 application using Vite, VueJS 3, InertiaJS and Quasar. I installed Quasar with the Vite Plugin [Doc here](https://quasar.dev/start/vite-plugin). Now my problem is that I want to use the Flex Addons to have responsive margin/padding [Flex addon](https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/introduction-to-flexbox#responsive-design), but in the documentation it is written that it needs to be enabled through `quasar.config.js > framework > cssAddon: true` , but I don't have a `quasar.config.js` file. I only have a `vite.config.js` file and my `app.js` root file where I load Quasar.

So is there an other way to enable cssAddon with vite plugin ? And is there an other way to have responsive margin without enabling cssAddon ?

Thanks for your help :)

This is my `app.js` file

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { Quasar } from 'quasar';
import quasarLang from 'quasar/lang/fr';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent} from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'

import AppLayout from './Layouts/AppLayout.vue';

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(Quasar, {
                plugins: {},
                lang: quasarLang,
            })
            .mount(el);
    }
})
```

This is my `vite.config.js` file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { quasar, transformAssetUrls } from '@quasar/vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                //'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {},
            },
        }),
        quasar({
            sassVariables: 'resources/sass/quasar-variables.scss',
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});
```

I tried to add `cssAddon:true` under Quasar in both files but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the sass file in your app.js (you're already importing the index.sass).

```
// Import Quasar css
import "quasar/src/css/index.sass";
import "quasar/src/css/flex-addon.sass";
```